# Inserting data from frontend in foreign key through query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to pass the data (post method)  from Angular to Postgresql via Nodejs. How to insert foreign key value from frontend (dynamically) in  insert query ?

```
query1:
 INSERT INTO tab_student (name_student, id_teacher_fk)
 VALUES ('abc', 
       (SELECT id_teacher FROM tab_teacher WHERE id_teacher_pk = ? )
//how do we get the foreign key id_teacher_fk from frontend 

 query 2:
INSERT INTO tab_student (name_student, id_teacher_fk)
VALUES ('rich man', LAST_INSERT_ID())
```

Comment: @wildplasser   how do I insert the value into foreign key from frontend ,should I use  "INSERT INTO emp (name,id) values ('abc',LAST_INSERT_ID())" ?

Comment: There is no `last_insert_id()` in Postgres. Are you looking for [`lastval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html)?

Comment: What information does the *frontend* have on the teacher? Is the teacher allready present in the tab_teachers table?

Comment: frontend on teacher  : teacher_id ,name , designation department . frontend on student : stud_id ,name,class  (At the backend  teacher_id is a foreign key in student table how could i update teacher_id in student table ?  )